# Path tracing in mapView in ios6

Tags: iphone, path, gps, mapkit, trace

i added MapView and and required condition for showing  current location , and with button functionality added just this method from apple documentation.

```
- (IBAction)refreshMapMethod:(id)sender
```

{

```
double latitude = 39.281516;
double longitude =-76.580806;


MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]    initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude) addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
[mapItem setName:@"Name of your location"];
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];

/////
////////

CLLocation* fromLocation = mapItem.placemark.location;

// Create a region centered on the starting point with a 10km span

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(fromLocation.coordinate, 10000, 10000);

// Open the item in Maps, specifying the map region to display.

[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:mapItem]
               launchOptions:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:region.center], MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey,
                              [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinateSpan:region.span], MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey, nil]];
```

}

after pressing button i am getting new view with all the functionality like add annotation on map view with long press, tracing path and many more .how this is happening with small function

any idea pleas help .

Answer (score 0):

Both `openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:` and `openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:` will open the Apple Maps application (and put your application into the background).  Probably this isn't what you intended.